# Linux: Match an expression, then remove the entire related block

Tags: linux, awk, sed, gnu, vi

Config file looks like this (I have to go through hundreds of them):

```
    define host {
        host_name   db.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.10
        use         yyy-server
        parents     router.xxx.yyy
    }
    define host {
        host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.48
        use         yyy-drac
        parents     router.xxx.yyy

    }
    define service {
            use             disk-opt-service
            host_name       db.xxx.yyy
    }
```

My job is to remove any and all blocks that contain db.xxx.yyy
so that the result would simply look like this (top and bottom block removed, since they each contain db.xxx.yyy in the block):

```
    define host {
        host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.48
        use         yyy-drac
        parents     router.xxx.yyy

    }
```

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Which error are you experiencing?

Comment: I have attempted using grep -a4 -b2 db.* etc. but I am getting either higher or lower lines than I what works due to some blocks having more lines than others, as in my example.
I am not sure how to even think through this one much, match the db.xx but then go backwards to the beginning of the block (in this case either ;define host' or 'define service' and then pruning from those entries to the next brace '}' - does that make sense?

Comment: Please [add your attempts and their results to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45968630/edit).

Comment: Do you want blocks that contain `foodb.xxx.yyybar` or other strings that contain `db.xxx.yyy` treated the same as if they contained exactly `db.xxx.yyy` or not? Do you want to match on `db.xxx.yyy` no matter where it appears in the block (e.g. as the `parents` value) or only when it's the `host_name` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -Ez 's/define (host|service) \{[^}]+db\.xxx\.yyy[^{}]+\}//g' file
```

- `-z` - treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII ‘NUL’ character) instead of a newline

The output:

```
define host {
    host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
    address     10.5.220.48
    use         yyy-drac
    parents     router.xxx.yyy

}
```

Comment: My `sed` doesn't include a `-z` option. Is this a GNUism?

Comment: This looks like it works perfectly!
I am going to have to study this solution and understand each character and piece of logic it involves.
This is going to save me probably 20 + hours of work, plus however I can use it in the future, of course :-)

Comment: @ghoti yes, `-z` is a GNUism which attempts to have sed read a whole file at a time into it's buffer. It works the same as using `-v RS='\0'` in a POSIX awk which of course is somewhat hit or miss since it'll fail for files that contain `\0` characters which is why in GNU awk we use `-v RS='^$'` instead to robustly read the whole file at once (and robustly in POSIX awk we build up the record in the main script body using `{rec = rec $0 RS}` and then process `rec` in the END section). If the input doesn't contain NULs though then it works fine as long as your input file isn't huge of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Awk One-Liner:**

```
awk -v RS='}\n' '/db.xxx/{next} {print $0,RS}' file
```

- Record separator is "}\n" .  If record contains pattern "db.xxx" then
  ignore and continure to next record else print record including RS
  i.e "}" [requires GNU-Awk with multichar RS]

Output:

```
define host {
    host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
    address     10.5.220.48
    use         yyy-drac
    parents     router.xxx.yyy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have name to value mappings in your input, the most robust and easily extensible solution is to first create an array (`f[]` below) to hold those name to value mappings and then just access the values by their names, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/define.*{/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    f[$1] = $2
    block = block $0 ORS
    if ( /}/ ) {
        if ( f["host_name"] != "db.xxx.yyy" ) {
            printf "%s", block
        }
        inBlock = block = ""
        delete f
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

That will working any awk on any UNIX system and since it's doing a string comparison on a specific field instead of a regexp comparison on the whole block it will not get confused by the value you're looking for showing up in the wrong field and/or regexp metacharacters and/or partially matching and obviously you can easily change it to look for combinations of fields or whatever else you need to test for. It also only reads one block at a time into memory so it'll work no matter how large your input file is.

```
$ cat file
When chapman billies leave the street,
And drouthy neibors, neibors, meet;
As market days are wearing late,
And folk begin to tak the gate,
While we sit bousing at the nappy,
An' getting fou and unco happy,

    define host {
        host_name   db.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.10
        use         yyy-server
        parents     router.xxx.yyy
    }
    define host {
        host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.48
        use         yyy-drac
        parents     router.xxx.yyy

    }
    define service {
            use             disk-opt-service
            host_name       db.xxx.yyy
    }

We think na on the lang Scots miles,
The mosses, waters, slaps and stiles,
That lie between us and our hame,
Where sits our sulky, sullen dame,
Gathering her brows like gathering storm,
Nursing her wrath to keep it warm.

 - Tam O'Shanter by Robert Burns
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
When chapman billies leave the street,
And drouthy neibors, neibors, meet;
As market days are wearing late,
And folk begin to tak the gate,
While we sit bousing at the nappy,
An' getting fou and unco happy,

    define host {
        host_name   drac.vs2.xxx.yyy
        address     10.5.220.48
        use         yyy-drac
        parents     router.xxx.yyy

    }

We think na on the lang Scots miles,
The mosses, waters, slaps and stiles,
That lie between us and our hame,
Where sits our sulky, sullen dame,
Gathering her brows like gathering storm,
Nursing her wrath to keep it warm.

 - Tam O'Shanter by Robert Burns
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*define/{:a;N;/^\s*}/M!ba;/db\.xxx\.yyy/d}' file
```

Match a line beginning with `define` and append further lines to it until matching a line beginning with `}`. If these lines contain the string `db.xxx.yyy` delete them.